# How to create a background music?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mediaelement, background-music

I need to run a background music in WP7 Silverlight application. I need it to keep playing when navigating between pages.

Also I don't want it to stop when another sound effect is played.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MediaElement to do that or use XNA SoundEffects but I have a better solution. Create a SilverXNA project for your app. You don't really need to use XNA but this project automatically creates some stuff which makes life easier. You can use this to build a Silverlight App with no problems.

After creating the project include your sound file in the project say "7am.mp3" and set it's build action to "Content".

Create a song in GamePage.xaml.cs:

```
Song music;
```

Now add this in OnNavigatedTo():

```
music = contentManager.Load<Song>("7am");
```

After this you can play this song as:

```
MediaPlayer.Play(music);
```

You may set the volume etc.

So, why this approach? Well, because according to technical certification guidelines you cannot interrupt a user if he is already listening to a song and SoundEffects class cannot be used for background music thus this method is the only way to get such flexibility.

You can use `MediaPlayer.GameHasControl` to see if user is playing music or not.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in referencing `Microsoft.Xna.Framework` then using the following function:

```
public static void PlaySound(string soundFile)
{
    var stream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(soundFile, UriKind.Relative)).Stream;

    if (stream != null)
    {
        var effect = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
        Microsoft.Xna.Framework.FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
        effect.Play();
    }
}
```

http://spacemigas.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/overcoming-windows-phone-7-mediaelement-limitations/

Comment: Still need to know how to make the background music loops as long as the the application is running..